# How to display two divs with p tags on the same line

Tags: css, html, image

I need to display 2 divs on the same line but they both have p tags in them and one of them has an image, which i need so i cant get rid of them, so i need a workaround to the problem 
Thanks in advance ;)

see code below :

HTML

```
<div class="MainMenu">
        <a href="home.php"><p>HOME</p></a>
        <a href="#"><p>ABOUT</p></a>
        <a href="store.php"><p>STORE</p></a>        
    </div>

    <div class="MainMenuBasket">
        <img src="../Images/jigsoar-icons/PNG/light/64px/64_cart.png" width="px" height="px" />

        <a href="#"><p>BASKET</p></a>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.MainMenu{width: 680px; float: left; margin-top:25px;}
.MainMenu a{text-decoration: none; color: #FFF; }
.MainMenu a:link {color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu a:active {color: #; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu a:hover {background-color: #7D3B05; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu a:visited {color: #; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu p{display: inline; font-size: 18px; padding-left: 20px;}

.MainMenuBasket{float: left; margin-top:25px;}
.MainMenuBasket a{text-decoration:none; color: #FFF;}
.MainMenuBasket a:link {color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket a:active {text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket a:hover {background-color: #7D3B05; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket p {display: inline; font-size: 18px;  padding left: 20px;}
```

Comment: it is in the same line right?? http://jsfiddle.net/2cZUw/1/

Comment: Why you need add `<p>` tag in `<a>`. Removing them and adding css to `<a>` is a better idea.

Comment: I'd suggest working with an unordered list, instead of the code you're using right now.

Comment: I have already tried that, but i can't get it to work :?

Answer (score 3):

Change the width of the `.MainMenu`

```
.MainMenu {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/qY642/1/

Answer (score 0):

add the attribute "position:absolute" and "float:right" to .MainMenuBasket. Now play with the attribute "left" of this class. It should align properly in the right.

In future try using the CSS library bootstrap http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/. Its very easy to create such divs with that.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want both `div` on same line , you need to set `float:left` for first div and `float:right` to second div.

**Try this :**

```
.MainMenuBasket{float: right; margin-top:25px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `width` and add `display:table-cell` to `.MainMenu` and remove `float:left` from `.MainMenuBasket`

```
.MainMenu{display:table-cell; margin-top:25px; background:violet}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2cZUw/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Is this you need?

**CSS**

```
.MainMenu{width: 680px; float: left; margin-top:25px; background:violet;float:left; width:300px;}
.MainMenu a{text-decoration: none; color: #FFF;display: inline; font-size: 18px; padding-left: 20px; }
.MainMenu a:link {color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu a:active {color: #; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu a:hover {background-color: #7D3B05; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenu a:visited {color: #; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket{float: left; margin-top:25px; background:maroon}
.MainMenuBasket a{text-decoration:none; color: #FFF;display: inline; font-size: 18px;  padding left: 20px;}
.MainMenuBasket a:link {color: #FFF; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket a:active {text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket a:hover {background-color: #7D3B05; text-decoration: none;}
.MainMenuBasket a:visited {text-decoration: none;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="MainMenu">
    <a href="home.php">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="store.php">STORE</a>        
</div>

<div class="MainMenuBasket">
    <img src="../Images/jigsoar-icons/PNG/light/64px/64_cart.png" width="px" height="px" />
    <a href="#">BASKET</a>
</div>
```